# Update table with value from selected option, php

Tags: php, html

I have site with selection i am using

[image]

i want to update value in the table when i choose from dropbox and press update button

```
<form action="post">
  <h5 class="card-title">Nájomník</h5>
  <select name="id_najomnik" id="id_najomnik">
    <?php while($r = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $r['id_najomnik']; ?>" <?php if($r[ 'id_najomnik']==$ detaily[ 'id_najomnik']) echo 'selected'; ?> class="card-text">
      <?php echo $r['meno'];echo ' ' ;echo $r['priezvisko']; }?>
    </option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="update.php" role="button">Prepoj</a>
    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Späť</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

this is the update.php file

```
<?php
    require_once 'nav.php';
    require_once 'conn.php';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $meno = $_POST['meno'];
    $priezvisko = $_POST['priezvisko'];
    $isSuccess = $crud->updateNajomnici($id, $meno, $priezvisko);
?>
```

Here are the functions i am using to get results

```
public function getNajomnicidetaily($id){
    $sql = "SELECT id_najomnik, meno,priezvisko,id_byt,nazov_budovy,nazov_bloku,mesto,ulica,cislo,psc,podlazie,rozloha,pocet_izieb,mesacny_najom, if(balkon=1, 'Áno', 'Nie') as balkon,if(pivnica=1, 'Áno', 'Nie') as pivnica, if(garaz=1, 'Áno', 'Nie') as garaz FROM `detail` where id_byt= :id";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindparam(':id', $id);     
    $stmt->execute();  
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    return $result;
}

public function getNajomniciudaje()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `najomnik` order by id_najomnik desc";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

any help? (please don't judge my code, i started learning php yesterday)

i hope someone will get the explanation

```
public function updateNajomnici($id, $meno, $priezvisko){
    $sql = "UPDATE `najomnik` SET meno = :meno, priezvisko = :priezvisko; WHERE id_najomnik=:id";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindparam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindparam(':meno', $meno);
    $stmt->bindparam(':priezvisko', $priezvisko);
    $stmt->execute();  
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    return $result;
}
```

edit, this is in the same php file as form

```
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $detaily = $crud->getNajomnicidetaily($id);
}
```

Comment: which value do you want to update, and in which table? We can't see any table. P.S. Actually your code is a lot better than many we see on this site.

Comment: well thanks for that ;), so i need to update 'najomnik' and value 'meno' and also 'priezvisko'

Comment: Ah you mean in a database table? Please [edit] the question to show us your `updateNajomnici` function.

Comment: yes i have everything from the database and uploading it to the site (just for test atm), I can send you the values from the table if it is needed

Comment: Ok so, in the HTML form, you have `<select name="id_najomnik"`, so that means when you submit the form you have to look for a value with that name, e.g. you would be expecting to find the selected value inside `$_POST['id_najomik']`. Your form doesn't have any other fields yet, so there would only be one value inside `$_POST`. It's not clear to me where you're expecting the other two to come from?

Comment: If this is your actual code, it should throw a syntax error here: `$ detaily[ 'id_najomnik']`. You can't have a space between the `$` and the variable name.

Comment: Also you have another problem because your form doesn't have any proper buttons - only hyperlinks. They can only cause a GET request, not a POST, and they will not submit the form properly. You're doing well after 1 day but I think you need to find a tutorial or two which teaches fully about HTML forms and PHP.

Comment: i wanted to do it with button but i don't know how

Comment: `<button type="submit">Click me</button>` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: yeah, but with php combined to make it working

Comment: Well that button will submit the form to PHP. But also you need to answer where you are expecting the values `$meno, $priezvisko` to come from? Are you intending to add more fields into your form? It looks like they are contained in the text of your `<option>`, but the text of an `<option>` is not submitted in the form, only the `value` part is sent. Maybe actually you don't need to store these extra values your table, you should only update the ID. If you need to know those other fields which relate to the ID you should find them in the `detail` table.

Comment: well i want to change the value meno and priezvisko, najomnik is connected to detail table, this table is view with joins, this is the look of table najomnik [(here is the link to picture)](https://ctrlv.link/8cDb), and the detail table isn't actually a table but just a view [(here is the link to picture)](https://ctrlv.link/MgnV). If you've got any other idea how should I do it, I would appreciate it

Comment: it cannot be changed through id_najomnik, so easiest to change is just 'meno' and 'priezvisko' and it will be connected to that same id (or at least from my view)

Comment: But every time you select an id_najomik value and save it in the najomnik table, it has the same meno and priezvisko values associated with it, yes? Because they are always related in the dropdown list. So actually that's redundant, because you already know those from the detail view. All you need to store in the najomik table is the ID.

Comment: so the function updateNajomnici should look how? if I may ask

Comment: Well I don't know, it's a bit unclear what precsiely you're trying to do. And I can't understand anything from the names of the tables or fields really, because I don't speak the right language (is it Polish, maybe?). Looking at the query, maybe you want to change the values associated with that ID, rather than changing the ID associated with some other values? In that case your form should contain textboxes for the two fields so the user can edit them, rather than a dropdown list where they can merely select an existing value.

Comment: my goal is to just create a dropdown selection, if I choose another name than there is and submit it would change the value from the previous name to the new name. Meno is Firstname and Priezvisko is Lastname (it's just in my language)

Comment: If you want the user to choose a name from a fixed list, then you should have a separate table which contains all the possible names and their IDs. Then you get the data from that table and show it in the dropdown selection. When the user makes the selection, you take the ID they selected and store it in a different table, presumably associated with some other data. If you later want to know what name that stored ID relates to, you can do a SELECT query and JOIN the two tables together by the ID, to get the result.